# How to access MatTableDataSource in custom Thingsboard widget?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, thingsboard, angular-material-table

I have developed a few custom Thingsboard widgets. It seems that I am able to access much of `@angular/material` from within my widget code. I am utilizing `mat-table` successfully, but in order to easily support pagination/filtering/sorting etc. I would like to utilize the `MatTableDataSource` class - this is resulting in an error as this class is apparently not exposed. How can I access `MatTableDataSource` from within my custom widget code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for 3.3.4.1 version you can't import so can't use such classes in JS section of custom widget.
I just `grep` the source code and [found nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJRgA.jpg) about MatTableDataSource.
[There](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/issues/6517) is similar question in the official bugtracker and there is no suggestion as well (16/06/2022).

Comment: do you have any further information @devaskim? I have already stated that I've been unable to do it - would you happen to be able to share how you confirmed this? or whether there is any way to work around it?

Comment: I [could find](https://imgur.com/a/jKFCoFF) any export of this class in Thingsboard source code. Unfortunately, at the moment I don't know any workaround

Comment: By the way [the same question](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/issues/6517) is without any answer for 3 months.

Comment: Yeah, I'd seen that Github question too :/ oh well. Thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @pooley1994 If you are building your instance from source code (TB CE version), you can export this class as it has already done for [some RxJS API](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/blob/master/ui-ngx/src/app/modules/home/models/widget-component.models.ts#L266-L273).

Comment: Thanks for following up @devaskim. We are not building our TB from source. For now I am just opting to implement table functionality in absence of `MatTableDataSource`.